# What is wrong with this Excel Chart x-axis assignment?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am using VBA to update the series' for several charts. I have some charts that show 3 series. I can update those fine, but when I try to update the `x-axis` I get errors. Here is what I've got so far:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & Sheets(1).Range("P5", Sheets(1).Cells(5, Sheets(1).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address).Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal)
```

I have tried testing each part of this assignment and each part works like it should.

[image: Watches for the parts of the assignment]

I have the correct chart active and the correct values are being selected for the assignment. This is the first time I've worked on charts through VBA so I'm sure I'm missing something painfully obvious.

Some additional code that I've got:

```
If Counter = 4 Then
    Dim XAxisRng
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
    With Sheets(1)
        Set XAxisRng = .Range("P5", .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    End With

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & XAxisRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & Sheets(1).Range("P6:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(1).Cells(6, Sheets(1).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "6").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=" & Sheets(2).Range("P6:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(2).Cells(6, Sheets(2).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "6").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "=" & Sheets(3).Range("P6:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(3).Cells(6, Sheets(3).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "6").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
```

**UPDATE**

I have updated my code to the following:

```
If Counter = 4 Then
    Dim XAxisRng As Range, ChtObj As ChartObject, Ser As Series
    Set ChtObj = Worksheets(Counter).ChartObjects(Chart) 'Chart is the name of the chart. I have 12 charts that I'm updating
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
    With Sheets(1)
        Set XAxisRng = .Range("P5", .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    End With

    With ChtObj
        Set Ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection(Coll) 'It errors on this line with Invalid Parameter
        Ser.XValues = "=" & XAxisRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal)
    End With
End If
```

It runs to this line `Set Ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection(1)` and then I get the error of:

> Invalid Parameter

I did try just using a number instead of the variable for the series collection number but still get the error.

**UPDATE 2**

Here's the whole of my code:

```
Sub Macro5()
    Dim Counter, Chart, ChartNum
    Dim C As Range, B As Range, A As Integer
    Dim r1, r2, MultipleRange As Range
    Counter = 1

    For x = Counter To 4 Step 1
        ChartNum = 15
        Chart = "Chart " & ChartNum
        Application.Worksheets(Counter).Activate
        'A = Range("A2") 'This is not needed

        'Set C = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft) 'ActiveCell
        'C.Select   'This will show you what is being set to C
        Set B = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)   'This is giving you the last column in row 6
        'B.Select   'This will show you what is being set to B

        If Counter > 1 And Count < 4 Then
            ChartNum = ChartNum - 2
        End If
        If Counter < 4 Then
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("P5", B)

            Set r1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft) 'C  'C is not needed anywhere and neither is B
            Set r2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(7, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)   'This is giving you the last column in row 6

            ChartNum = ChartNum + 1
            If ChartNum = 14 Then
                ChartNum = ChartNum + 1
            End If
            Chart = "Chart " & ChartNum
            Set MultipleRange = Application.Union(Range("P5", r1), Range("P7", r2))
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=MultipleRange

            Set r2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(8, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

            ChartNum = ChartNum + 1
            Chart = "Chart " & ChartNum
            Set MultipleRange = Application.Union(Range("P5", r1), Range("P8", r2))
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=MultipleRange

            Set r2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(9, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

            ChartNum = ChartNum + 1
            Chart = "Chart " & ChartNum
            Set MultipleRange = Application.Union(Range("P5", r1), Range("P9", r2))
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=MultipleRange

            Set r2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(10, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

            ChartNum = ChartNum + 1
            Chart = "Chart " & ChartNum
            Set MultipleRange = Application.Union(Range("P5", r1), Range("P10", r2))
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=MultipleRange

            Set r2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(11, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

            ChartNum = ChartNum + 1
            Chart = "Chart " & ChartNum
            Set MultipleRange = Application.Union(Range("P5", r1), Range("P11", r2))
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=MultipleRange
        End If
        If Counter = 1 Then
            Set r2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(12, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

            ChartNum = ChartNum + 1
            Chart = "Chart " & ChartNum
            Set MultipleRange = Application.Union(Range("P5", r1), Range("P12", r2))
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=MultipleRange

            Set r2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(13, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

            ChartNum = ChartNum + 1
            Chart = "Chart " & ChartNum
            Set MultipleRange = Application.Union(Range("P5", r1), Range("P13", r2))
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=MultipleRange

            Set r2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(14, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

            ChartNum = ChartNum + 1
            Chart = "Chart " & ChartNum
            Set MultipleRange = Application.Union(Range("P5", r1), Range("P14", r2))
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=MultipleRange

            Set r2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(15, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

            ChartNum = ChartNum + 1
            Chart = "Chart " & ChartNum
            Set MultipleRange = Application.Union(Range("P5", r1), Range("P15", r2))
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=MultipleRange

            Set r2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(16, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

            ChartNum = ChartNum + 1
            Chart = "Chart " & ChartNum
            Set MultipleRange = Application.Union(Range("P5", r1), Range("P16", r2))
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=MultipleRange

            Set r2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(17, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

            ChartNum = ChartNum + 1
            Chart = "Chart " & ChartNum
            Set MultipleRange = Application.Union(Range("P5", r1), Range("P17", r2))
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=MultipleRange
        End If
        If Counter = 4 Then
            Dim XAxisRng As Range, ChtObj As ChartObject, Ser As Series ', Coll
            Set ChtObj = Worksheets(Counter).ChartObjects(Chart)
            'Coll = 1
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            With Sheets(1)
                Set XAxisRng = .Range("P5", .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
            End With

            With ChtObj
                Set Ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
                Ser.XValues = "=" & XAxisRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal)
                'Ser.Values = "=" & Sheets(1).Range("P6:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(1).Cells(6, Sheets(1).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "6").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
                'Set Ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection(Coll + 1)
                'Ser.Values = "=" & Sheets(1).Range("P6:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(1).Cells(6, Sheets(1).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "6").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
                'Set Ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection(Coll + 2)
                'Ser.Values = "=" & Sheets(1).Range("P6:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(1).Cells(6, Sheets(1).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "6").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
            End With

            'ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & XAxisRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal)
            'ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & Sheets(1).Range("P6:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(1).Cells(6, Sheets(1).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "6").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
            'ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=" & Sheets(2).Range("P6:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(2).Cells(6, Sheets(2).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "6").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
            'ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "=" & Sheets(3).Range("P6:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(3).Cells(6, Sheets(3).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "6").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)

            ChartNum = ChartNum + 3
            Chart = "Chart " & ChartNum
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & Sheets(1).Range("P7:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(1).Cells(7, Sheets(1).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "7").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=" & Sheets(2).Range("P7:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(2).Cells(7, Sheets(2).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "7").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "=" & Sheets(3).Range("P7:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(3).Cells(7, Sheets(3).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "7").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)

            ChartNum = ChartNum + 1
            Chart = "Chart " & ChartNum
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & Sheets(1).Range("P8:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(1).Cells(8, Sheets(1).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "8").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=" & Sheets(2).Range("P8:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(2).Cells(8, Sheets(2).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "8").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "=" & Sheets(3).Range("P8:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(3).Cells(8, Sheets(3).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "8").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)

            ChartNum = ChartNum + 1
            Chart = "Chart " & ChartNum
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & Sheets(1).Range("P9:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(1).Cells(9, Sheets(1).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "9").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=" & Sheets(2).Range("P9:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(2).Cells(9, Sheets(2).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "9").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "=" & Sheets(3).Range("P9:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(3).Cells(9, Sheets(3).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "9").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)

            ChartNum = ChartNum + 1
            Chart = "Chart " & ChartNum
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & Sheets(1).Range("P10:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(1).Cells(10, Sheets(1).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "10").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=" & Sheets(2).Range("P10:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(2).Cells(10, Sheets(2).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "10").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "=" & Sheets(3).Range("P10:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(3).Cells(10, Sheets(3).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "10").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)

            ChartNum = ChartNum + 1
            Chart = "Chart " & ChartNum
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Activate
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & Sheets(1).Range("P11:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(1).Cells(11, Sheets(1).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "11").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=" & Sheets(2).Range("P11:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(2).Cells(11, Sheets(2).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "11").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "=" & Sheets(3).Range("P11:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(3).Cells(11, Sheets(3).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "11").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)

        End If
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Next x
    'Workbooks("Name").Activate
End Sub
Function GetLetterFromNumber(Number)
    GetLetterFromNumber = Split(Cells(1, Number).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
End Function

Function GetArray(Range1 As Range)
    Dim Test() As String, cell As Range, i As Integer
    i = 0
    ReDim Test(0)
    For Each cell In Range1
        ReDim Preserve Test(i)
        Test(i) = cell.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
    GetArray = Test
End Function
```

Most of this works fine. It gets to the line below `If Counter = 4 Then` where it errors. The line is:

```
Set Ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
```

The error is:

> Invalid Parameter

Is there something somewhere that I'm missing that is messing me up?

Comment: `xlAl` should be `xlA1` -  you have the letter L there, not a one.

Comment: I have updated that. It's hard to tell the font makes them very similar looking. Now I get an error that says `Invalid Parameter`

Comment: @Mike see if the code in my answer below helps you solve this issue

Comment: You don't need the equal sign in your string; try this: `.XValues = Sheets(1).Range(...`

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
Dim XAxisRng As Range

With Sheets(1)
    Set XAxisRng = .Range("P5", .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
End With

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & XAxisRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal)
```

---

### Edit 1

Give it another try, this time avoid using `ActiveChart`, and usee fully qualified variables and objects.

```
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
Dim XAxisRng As Range
Dim Ser As Series

If Counter = 4 Then

    Set ChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1") '<-- modify "Chart 1" to your chart's name
    With Sheets(1)
        Set XAxisRng = .Range("P5", .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    End With

    With ChtObj
        Set Ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
        Ser.XValues = "=" & XAxisRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal)

        ' rest of your code goes here

    End With
    ' other code you might have

End If ' closing If Counter = 4
```

Comment: I still get the `Invalid Parameter` error with your update.

Comment: @Mike  can you paste the rest of the relevant code ?

Comment: Try just using `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = XAxisRng`

Comment: When I make that change it gives the error `Type Mismatch`

Comment: @Mike tr the code I've added under **Edit 1** and let me know if it works for you

Comment: I updated to this: `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & XAxisRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal)` and I still get the `Invalid Parameter` error. I'm going to make further edits and post it to my question.

Comment: @Mike the code you've posted is not the one I have here, please use it exactly as I have it, you changed so many parameters , there's no way to debug where the error is coming from

Comment: I have done so with the exception of the chart name. I have 12 charts that I am needing to do this for and I cycle through the names so I have a variable that will do it for me. Otherwise, I have everything the same way that you do. I still get the error about the `Invalid Parameter` at the line `Set Ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection(1)`

Comment: @Mike I saw that now you have the same code, strange since it's running nicely in my tests

Comment: Agreed, it is strange. I don't understand where this is coming from.